# This antd library component is giving me error while converting Javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

its in the handleChange function, while setState{ imageUrl }

When I use just javascript the imagepreview is shown but shows error in typescript

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-6yn9v

```
import { Upload, Icon, message } from "antd";

function getBase64(img: any, callback: any) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => callback(reader.result));
  reader.readAsDataURL(img);
}

function beforeUpload(file: any) {
  const isJPG = file.type === "image/jpeg";
  if (!isJPG) {
    message.error("You can only upload JPG file!");
  }
  const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
  if (!isLt2M) {
    message.error("Image must smaller than 2MB!");
  }
  return isJPG && isLt2M;
}

function Avatar() {
  const initialState = {
    loading: false
  };

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);

  const handleChange = (info: any) => {
    if (info.file.status === "uploading") {
      setState({ ...state, loading: true });
      return;
    }
    if (info.file.status === "done") {
      // Get url from response in real world.
      getBase64(
        info.file.originFileObj,
        (imageUrl: any): any => setState({ ...state, 
            imageUrl, // shows error here but works fine in javascript
             loading: false })
      );
    }
  };

  const uploadButton = (
    <div>
      <Icon type={state.loading ? "loading" : "plus"} />
      <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
    </div>
  );
  const { imageUrl }: any = state;
  return (
    <Upload
      name="avatar"
      listType="picture-card"
      className="avatar-uploader"
      showUploadList={false}
      action="http://192.168.1.172:9595/upload/multiple"
      beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      {imageUrl ? <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" /> : uploadButton}
    </Upload>
  );
}
```

This antd library component is giving me error while converting Javascript to typescript,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that React.useState infers the type of the state value it manages based on the initialState value that is passed in. So what you have:

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false
};
const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);
```

If you hover of state/setState in the Codesandbox, you can see that the inferred type of state is

```
{
  loading: boolean
}
```

There isn't an imageUrl field in this state type, so it's illegal to try to set that field.

There are multiple ways to tell Typescript that state can have an `imageUrl` field as well. One would be to explicitly annotate initialState with the desired type. Another would be to annotate the `React.useState` call itself.

```
interface AvatarState {
  loading: boolean;
  imageUrl?: string;
}
...
const initialState: AvatarState = {
  loading: false
};
const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);
```

```
interface AvatarState {
  loading: boolean;
  imageUrl?: string;
}
...
const initialState = {
  loading: false
};
const [state, setState] = React.useState<AvatarState>(initialState);
```